# Collaborative editor other users cursor modification

Tags: codemirror, codemirror-modes, firepad, ui-codemirror

I am using CodeMirror and Firepad to create a webapp for collaborative code editor. I want to modify the styling of the cursors. I am able to modify the cursor of the user using the CodeMirror CSS class .CodeMirror-cursor. But I am not able to modify the cursors of other users. I want to add a name at the top of the cursor to identify the user of the cursor. Even before that I am attempting to resize the other user cursors. How can I do this?